# Group by on columns with repeated data

Tags: sql-server

In the SQL Server I have a table with repeated data in few columns and NULL values in few other columns some thing similar show as below.

```
DirName | BillingNPI | Average | TotalClaims | MaxString | MinString | CorrectString
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AASTA   | 158967     |  10     |   20        |  NULL     |  NULL     |  Value
AASTA   | 158967     |  10     |   20        |  NULL     |  ValueSTA |  Value
AASTA   | 158967     |  10     |   20        |  STAValue |  NULL     |  Value
```

Now using `GROUP BY` I'm trying the output of my query to be

```
DirName | BillingNPI | Average | TotalClaims | MaxString | MinString | CorrectString
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AASTA   | 158967     |  10     |   20        |  STAValue |  ValueSTA |  Value
```

Do I have to use inner join on the same table to achieve this ?

Comment: You should aggregate by non null columns and perform `max` aggregation function for others. Sample: `select dirname, billingnpi, avarage, max( totalclaims) as totalclaims, max( maxstring) as maxstring, ... from your_table group by dirname, billingnpi, avarage`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I can post it as answer in order to check it as solution if you want. Do you know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Does this get what you need?

```
select 
  DirName , 
  BillingNPI , 
  Average , 
  TotalClaims , 
  max(isnull(MaxString,'') maxstring, 
  max(isnull(MinString,'') minstring,
  CorrectString
group by 
  DirName , 
  BillingNPI , 
  Average , 
  TotalClaims , 
  CorrectString
```

Comment: isnull not needed, ["except for COUNT, aggregate function ignore null values".](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)